# SSSD not authenticating to AD

Tags: active-directory, sssd

I have a cluster of 23 machines. CentOS 6.7  They have been successfully authenticating to AD via SSSD for over a year.

Unbeknownst to me, someone moved one computer out of the search base OU and renamed it from lowercase to uppercase.   It is now the only machine that cannot authenticate to AD.

sssd.conf has "case_sensitive = false" 
ive also changed "ldap_sasl_authid " from lowercase to upper to match AD but still cannot connect after clearing /var/lib/sss/db and sssd restart.  getent passwd only shows local accounts.

When compared to other machines that are still authenticating, every service and config file is the same.

Getting pushback from network folks on the rename.  Is there any way to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

fixed this by leaving the domain and rejoining with the correct lowercase name.  running the following.

- `net ads leave -S domain_controller -U admin_account`
- `net ads join createupn=host/server_name.domain.com -S domain_controller -U admin_account`

the original kerberos keytabs worked without recreation.